# Generate array from existing object's attribute

Tags: java, arrays, collections, sub-array

Let's consider we have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public String lastname;
}
```

Suppose we have collection for that `Person` class. How can I generate a new String collection which contains just `lastnames`?

We can do that easily by iterating, but I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Due to some dependencies I can't use Java 8.

Comment: Google: Java stream map

Comment: "We can do that easily by iterating but looking for most efficient way to do this." By most efficient do you mean less code, or performance-wise? Because even though you can make it a one-liner with Java8's map-streams, it will still do a loop behind the scenes.

Comment: looking for better performance solutions actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop and initialize your target collection with the right size:

```
String[] lastnames = new String[persons.size()]; // or new ArrayList(persons.size()), ...
for(int i=0;i<persons.size();i++){
    lastnames[i] = persons.get(i).getLastName();
}
```

This would be efficient (O(n)) if direct access is possible in both collections (persons and lastnames).